# Inserting data from scope to PHP variable with ajax request

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm searching for a way to insert scope data from inputs to a php variable, this is how my code look:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-app="Filter" ng-controller="InsertFilter">
<form>
    <label for="limit">Limit:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="limit" name="limit" ng-model="limit">
    <label for="page">Page:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="page" name="page" ng-model="page">
    <label for="from">From:</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="from" name="from" ng-model="from">
    <label for="to">To:</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="to" name="to" ng-model="to">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-top: 15px;">Show Report</button>
</form>
```

Ajax request in angular:

```
var FilterApp = angular.module('Filter', []);
      FilterApp.controller('InsertFilter', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.post("/api/data-dashboard.php").then(function(response){
      $scope.limit = /* ??? */;
  });
});
```

data-dashboard.php:

```
if (empty($_POST["from"])) {
$from = date('Y-m-d');

} else {
$from = $_POST["from"];
}

if (empty($_POST["to"])){
$week = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
$to = date('Y-m-d', $week);
} else {
$to = $_POST["to"];
}

if (empty($_POST["page"])) {
$page = 1;
} else {
$page = $_POST["page"];
}

if (empty($_POST["limit"])) {
$limit = 10;
} else {
$page = $_POST["page"];
}
```

Thanks for all kind responses.
*should I transfer input to json format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Collect all details form Angular HTTP Request use

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$from = request->from;
```

And pass parameter to $http.post

```
$http.post("/api/data-dashboard.php",{from:$scope.from}).then(function(response){});
```